# Retrieve data from combobox to other input fields

Tags: php

I am PHP beginner and am having problems creating a combobox or a drop down list. The combobox or drop down list contains stock names, when I click any stock, the stock code and producer should be displayed. I have attached the code please. My code works well to retrieve stock code alone. How do I make the stockcode and producer to be retrieved.

This is what I am doing

```
                <label class="col-lg-2 col-form-label" for="val-skill">Select Stock<span class="text-danger">*</span> </label>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                
                <select id="stockname" name="stockname" class="form-control" required="">
                
                <option value="0">Select Stock</option>
                <?php
                $ddaa = $pdo->query("SELECT id, stockname, stockno, producer FROM storemaster ORDER BY id");
                    
                    while ($data = $ddaa->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                    {                                   
                        echo "<option value='$data[stockno]', '$data[producer]'> $data[stockname]</option>";
                        
                    }
                ?>
                  </select>
                 </div>
            </div>
                

        
            
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Stock No</label>
          <div class="col-sm-6"><input  id="stockno" name="stockno" value="" class="form-control" type="text" readonly></div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Producer</label>
          <div class="col-sm-6"><input id="producer" name="producer" value="" class="form-control" type="text" ></div>
        </div>
        
        
        
        
    
    
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3"><br/><br/><br/>
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" value="Submit">
            </div>
        
         
         
      </form>
      
      
      
    </div>
  </div>
             <script>
                    document.getElementById("stockname").onchange = function () {

                    document.getElementById("stockno").value = this.value;
                    
                };
            </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//PHP
echo '<option value="'.$data['stockno'].'" data-producer="'.$data['producer'].'"> '.$data['stockname'].'</option>';


<!--HTML Javascript-->

<script>
  $('#stockname').on('change',function(){
  if($(this).val() !=0){
   $('#stockno').val($(this).val());
   $('#producer').val($(this).attr('data-producer'));
  }
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you but the code fetched only for stockno, producer field is blank. Please me out to progress on my learning curve. Thank you all

Comment: did u change the html option like this :
echo '<option value="'.$data['stockno'].'" data-producer="'.$data['producer'].'"> '.$data['stockname'].'</option>';

Comment: @ Hammad Ahmed khan. Yes for sure I did.

Comment: Hello Hammad, I still have not resolved this problem. Please help me out. Emeka